# What is the equivalent increment! on mongoid

Tags: mongoid

I am new to mongoid, I am trying to use increment! method and getting an error.

```
myinstance.increment!(:number_of_calls)
```

=> undefined method `increment!' for #Myinstance:0x00007faac25f8448

Comment: What is increment! ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably `Model#inc` in https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-persistence/#atomic though you have not said what you expect `increment!` to do.